# "Do not Distrub" stopped working

Tags: notification

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Today I noticed that even if I have turned on "Do not disturb", notification windows still pop up at top-right corner.

I verified this by running the command

```bsh
notify-send "very long title" "very long text"
```

This triggers a notification window regardless of if "Do not disturb" is switched on. See the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to diagnose what goes wrong?

Comment: It's a bit strange. After reboot it works again.

Comment: After another reboot it does not work again. There is something which goes wrong at random.